# What is the set of the accumulation points of this set?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Let $A := \{ \frac{1}{n} \mid n \in \mathbb{N} \}.$ I wish to find the boundary of $A$. Since $\overline{A} = A \cup \{ 0 \},$　there remains to find $\overline {\mathbb{R}\setminus A}.$ Since $\overline{\mathbb{R} \setminus A} = (\mathbb{R} \setminus A) \cup$ the set of all accumulation points of $\mathbb{R} \setminus A,$ knowing the latter solves the problem.

Comment: HINT: Is there any point of $A$ that is *not* an accumulation point of $\Bbb R\setminus A$?

Comment: Ah thanks. But is it also true that every point of $\mathbb{R} \setminus A $ is an accumulation point ?

Comment: Of $\Bbb R\setminus A$? Yes: just look at an open interval around any of them.